# Keeping the schema types from Pandas dataframe to Snowpark dataframe

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, snowpark

Snowpark has a problem / bug that it does not maintain the types between Pandas and Snowpark, nor does it allow to manually set its schema.

For instance,

```py
df1 = session.sql(sql).to_pandas()
df2 = session.create_dataframe(df)
```

The timestamp field on `df1` with `TimestampType` has become a `LongType`.

I've also tried to store the schema and use it, but same results.

```py
df1 = session.sql(sql)
df1_schema = df1.schema
df1 = df1.to_pandas()
df2 = session.create_dataframe(df, df1_schema)
```

Has anyone managed to deal with it?
This stops me from being able to write the `DataFrame` back to the table as it needs to be of `TimestampType` rather than `LongType`.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to recreate this in snowpark, it seems that the TimestampType is internally getting changed to LongType when pandas df is converted to snowpark df using create_dataframe() method.

Also, specifying schema parameter in create_dataframe() method w.r.t this scenario is not making any difference.
So, one way is to explicitly change the column to timestamp using to_timestamp() method.

```
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import sql_expr
df1 = session.sql("select * from timestamp_test")
df1 = df1.to_pandas()
df2 = session.create_dataframe(df1)
colCast = df2.withColumn("T", sql_expr("to_timestamp(T::string)"))
colCast.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success with this:

```
df1 = session.sql("select * from timestamp_test")
df1 = df1.to_pandas()
df1["T"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["T"])
df1["T"] = df1["T"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
df2 = session.create_dataframe(df1)
df2.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("table_name")
```

A second option that's more general. I saw it in an article somewhere and I didn't understand why they did it, until I saw some problems with the data types in Snowflake. To use it you need to build the table schema first:

```
# Create an empty table using the schema
df = session.create_dataframe([len(table_schema.names) * [None]], schema=table_schema)
df.na.drop().write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table(tbl)

# Populate the table
df = session.create_dataframe(data=df1, schema=table_schema)
df_snw.write.mode("append").save_as_table(tbl)
```